# Using Vite + React, global replacements using 'define' in 'vite.config.js' are not working

Tags: reactjs, vite

I suspect this issue is specific to the Vite+React combination. Testing was done using `vite serve`. **Note it works fine if doing `vite build`, only `vite serve` has this issue.**

In my vite.config.js, I use a 'define' for global constant replacement:

**vite.config.js**

```
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => ({
  plugins: [
    react(),
  ],
  define: {
    __BUILD_TIMESTAMP__: 'helloWorld123',
  }
}))
```

It does not work. There are 2 issues:

---

### 1. I get errors in the browser:

[image: console]

[image: sources]

---

### 2. Replacement does not occur:

If I work around the error by including a second set of quotes (`__BUILD_TIMESTAMP__: '"helloWorld123"'`) to silence the error, replacement still doesn't occur:

**file.jsx**

```
export function MyComponent() {
  return <div>Hello, __BUILD_TIMESTAMP__ </div>
}
```

Render in browser:

[image: browser]

---

Vite documentation on this is hard do come by. I am using the below:

- [Vite reference for 'define'](https://v2.vitejs.dev/config/#define)
- [Vite reference for vite.config.js](https://vitejs.dev/config/)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html), you need to use `JSON.stringify('v1.0.0')` for string.

> Vite uses esbuild defines to perform replacements, so value expressions must be a string that contains a **JSON-serializable value** (null, boolean, number, string, array, or object) or a single identifier.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

The first error is not about Vite or anything similar.  You are merely assigning a property named `"__BUILD_TIMESTAMP__"` the value of the identifier `helloWorld123`.  I can only imagine this identifier doesn't exist.

As for the replacement you are expecting to happen, this is a quote from the Vite documentation you reference, in its first paragraph:

> Entries will be defined as globals during dev and statically replaced during build.

It is telling you that **replacements** only happen during build.  It tells you that, while in DEV, no replacements are done and instead a global variable with the name you seek to replace will be defined (in the `window` object) whose value will be whatever is set in the `define` entry.

### UPDATE

The previous answer was written for Vite v4.  Version 5 works almost the same, but instead delegates the replacements to **ESBuild** during build.  The original question has a URL pointing to very old documentation (v2), so see [this one instead:  define](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define).

Comment: The value assigned is a string `'helloWorld123'`, not the variable helloWorld123. There is no requirement for this string to match an existing variable, and actually it works fine with `vite build` as-is, with no error.

Comment: it's not replacing at build for me - for HTML :(

Comment: @JobaDiniz check the link in the updated answer for Vite v5.